# Uncaught Error: RangeError: Value not in range: 3

Tags: flutter, list, dart

[image: DartPad ScreenShot]

I want to delete items one by one from a `List`.

I could also clear the whole List by using the `clear()` method but I don't want that.

If someone has a solution to this problem please point it out.

Thank you.

```
void main(){
 
  List<String> list =['first','second','3rd','4th','5th'];

  list.removeAt(0);
  list.removeAt(1);
  list.removeAt(2);
  list.removeAt(3);
  list.removeAt(4);

  
  print(list);
//   I don't want to clear all list at once
//   I want to remove one by one element from the list
//   list.clear();
//   list.map((e){
   
//   }).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you remove first 3 element, you do not have 3th element anymore. You can just

```
  list.removeAt(0);
  list.removeAt(0);
  list.removeAt(0);
  list.removeAt(0);
  list.removeAt(0);
```

or

```
  list.removeAt(4);
  list.removeAt(3);
  list.removeAt(2);
  list.removeAt(1);
  list.removeAt(0);
```

Comment: Appreciating! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it did. Also it is common practice to accept the answer that helped you

Answer (score 0):

When you remove first 3 elements you don't have 3th element anymore. To make it dynamic to the list length you can do it like so:

```
    void main() {
      List<String> list = ['first','second','3rd','4th','5th'];
      int length = list.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        list.removeAt(0);
      }
      print(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you debug it yourself with simple print statements, it will become obvious, what happens:

```
void main(){
 
  List<String> list =['first','second','3rd','4th','5th'];

  print(list);
  
  list.removeAt(0);
  
  print(list);
  
  list.removeAt(1);
  
  print(list);
  
  list.removeAt(2);
  
  print(list);
  
  list.removeAt(3);
  
  print(list);
  
  list.removeAt(4);
  
  print(list);
}
```

> [first, second, 3rd, 4th, 5th]

Removing the first element of this list:

> [second, 3rd, 4th, 5th]

Removing the second element of *that* list:

> [second, 4th, 5th]

Removing the third element of *that* list:

> [second, 4th]

And finally, trying to remove the fourth element of a list that no longer has four elements:

> Uncaught Error: RangeError: Value not in range: 3